# Modified recursive bubble-sort with threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, recursion, bubble-sort

I have to make a sort for university that splits an array in two and starts a thread for each half. If the amount of numbers in a thread is higher than a threshold it will again split the numbers in two threads, if it isn't it will bubble-sort the numbers. Then the resulting arrays are merged by the parent thread.

I will include the code that I wrote:

```java
public int[] bubbleSort4(int[] array, int threshold) {
        int middle = array.length/2;

        int[] array1;
        int[] array2;
        System.out.println("Whole array before sort" + Arrays.toString(array));

        array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, middle);
        System.out.println("Division before sort" + Arrays.toString(array1));
        array2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, middle, array.length);
        System.out.println("Division before sort" + Arrays.toString(array2));

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new BubbleSort4(array2, threshold));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new BubbleSort4(array1, threshold));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Divided array after sort" + Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.println("Divided array after sort" + Arrays.toString(array2));


        int[] result = merge(array1, array2);

        System.out.println("Merged divided arrays" + Arrays.toString(result));

        return result;
    }

// sorting thread
public class BubbleSort4 implements Runnable {
        private int[] ints;
        private int threshold;

        public BubbleSort4(int[] ints, int threshold) {
            this.ints = ints;
            this.threshold = threshold;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(ints.length > threshold) {
                bubbleSort4(ints, threshold);
            } else {
                bubbleSort1(ints);
            }
        }

    }
```

Here are the results from sorting 6 random numbers with a threshold of 2 (It works fine for 4 numbers) :

```
Whole array before sort[95663, 385695, 80250, 338138, 157477, 160282]
Division before sort[95663, 385695, 80250]
Division before sort[338138, 157477, 160282]
Whole array before sort[338138, 157477, 160282]
Whole array before sort[95663, 385695, 80250]
Division before sort[338138]
Division before sort[95663]
Division before sort[157477, 160282]
Division before sort[385695, 80250]
Divided array after sort[338138]
Divided array after sort[95663]
Divided array after sort[157477, 160282]
Divided array after sort[80250, 385695]
Merged divided arrays[157477, 160282, 338138]
Merged divided arrays[80250, 95663, 385695]
Divided array after sort[95663, 385695, 80250]
Divided array after sort[338138, 157477, 160282]
Merged divided arrays[95663, 338138, 157477, 160282, 385695, 80250]
```

edit: the problem was that my method was returning the new array into the void

Comment: Hint: Looking at the output, shouldn't `Merged divided arrays[80250, 95663, 385695]`  and `Divided array after sort[95663, 385695, 80250]` say the same thing?  Why don't they?  Hint 2:  the problem is in the `run()` method.

Comment: Thanks, so basically the threads return nothing but i don't understand why it works for the inner threads and for 4 numbers?